# parse page with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse this webpage and take some of information:

http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=778253364357513

```
import requests
page = requests.get("http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=778253364357513")

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

All_Information = soup.find(id="MainContent")

print(All_Information)
```

it seams all information between tag is hidden. when i run the code this data is returned.

```
<div class="tabcontent content" id="MainContent">
<div id="TopBox"></div>
<div id="ThemePlace" style="text-align:center">
<div class="box1 olive tbl z2_4 h250" id="Section_relco" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="box1 silver tbl z2_4 h250" id="Section_history" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="box1 silver tbl z2_4 h250" id="Section_tcsconfirmedorders" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Why is the information not there, and how can I find and/or access it?

Comment: _but all information is hidden?_ Is it? Are you asking us? Please clarify your question, see [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: That kind of information should be in your post, it's difficult to read as a comment.

Comment: excuse me. I was modified my question.

Answer (score 1):

The information that I assume you are looking for is not loaded in your request. The webpage makes additional requests after it has initally loaded. There are a few ways you can get that information.

You can try `selenium`. It is a python package that simulates a web browser. This allows the page to load all the information before you try to **scrape**.

Another way is to reverse enginneer the website and find out where it is getting the information you need.

Have a look at this link.
http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/instinfofast.aspx?i=778253364357513&c=57+

It is called by your page every few seconds, and it appears to contain all the pricing information you are looking for. It may be easier to call that webpage to get your information.

Comment: how you was get to this link?

Comment: You browser has a built in debugging tool. If you are using Chrome or Firefox, go to a page, press F12, go to the network tab, then reload the page. You will see all the requests made when loading that page and what information was returned.